# Combinatorial Problem with two variables

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a box there are 3 packages of pasta of shape 1, and with different weights: 300 gr, 400 gr, 500gr. In addition, there are 5 packages of paste of shape 2, with weights: 300gr, 350gr, 400gr, 500gr, 600gr,and 4 packages of pasta of shape 3, with weights 300gr, 350gr, 400gr, 500gr.

What is the probability that a random ordering of the packages will be such that pasta packages of the same weight will be one next to another, and/or each shape of pasta will be separate ?

The and/or part of the question is unclear to me. My interpretation is to count all the possibilities in which the same weight is one next to another, or the shape is separate or both. Does it makes sense ?

This is a probability question, but the main problem is combinatorial.

The number of possibilities is clearly :

$(3+5+4)! = 12!$

The number of possibilities for separate shapes is:

$3!\cdot 3!\cdot 4!\cdot5!$

i.e, 6 possibilities to order the shapes, with all the inner possibilities within each shape, right ?

My problem is with the weights...

Comment: "...5 packages of paste of shape 2... " but $6$ weights are listed. Also, clarify the and/or in the context

Comment: true blue nail, I have tried to be more clear.

Comment: The number of possible arrangements for the shapes is actually $\binom{12}{3}\binom{9}{5}\binom{4}{4} = \frac{12!}{3!4!5!}$.  Choose three of the twelve positions for shape 1 and five of the remaining nine positions for shape 2.  Then all four of the remaining four positions must be filled with shape 3.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean. What about the weights ?